# Watch all starred GitHub projects

Tags: github, github-api

I have hundreds of starred GitHub repos, but none of them are watched. How can I easily watch all my starred repos without enabling watching one at a time? I'm sure this is possible with the GitHub API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can do this with the API.  You can use the [`list repositories being starred`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-repositories-being-starred) endpoint to generate a list, e.g.:

```
curl -u <USER>:<API_KEY> https://api.github.com/user/starred
```

Then use the [`set a repository subscription`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/watching/#set-a-repository-subscription) endpoint to watch your list of starred repositories by setting  `subscribed` to `true`:

```
curl -X PUT -d {"subscribed":true} -u <USER>:<API_KEY> https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/subscription
```